# Java building query with CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, criteria, query-builder

I need to create query using java Criteria builder which would look like this 
`AND (column1 != value OR column2 != value)` i only managed to create `notEqual` which looks like this `builder.notEqual(root.get(column), value));` which translates to `AND column1 != value` what else i need to add to make it `AND (column1 != value OR column2 != value)`

Answer (score 0):

```
criteriaBuilder.or(criteriaBuilder.notEqual(root.get(column1), value),
                   criteriaBuilder.notEqual(root.get(column2), value))
```

You may also want to look into the [CriteriaBuilder javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaBuilder.html) for additional expressions.